# Vue 2 + Bootstrap-vue - dynamic attribute

Tags: vue.js, attributes, bootstrap-4

this is my first steps in **Vue 2** + **bootstrap-vue**, and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically change the name of an attribute, so that at a small screen resolution the tooltip changes its position.

JS code below works fine, but tooltip not changing his position =(
Please help me improve my mistake;

**.pug**

[image]
[image]

**JS**

```js
'use strict';

import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
    new Vue({
        el: '#freshbroccoli',
        data: {
            windowWidth: null,
            position: this.windowWidth >= 480 ? 'left' : 'bottom'
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
                this.getWindowWidth();
            });
        },
        methods: {
            getWindowWidth() {
                this.windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                console.log('this.windowWidth >= 480 ? \'left\' : \'bottom\'', this.windowWidth >= 480 ? 'left' : 'bottom', '\n', this.windowWidth);
            }
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
        }
    });
});
```

**Browser - Chrome**

[image]

**Browser console - Chrome**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: my old answer assumed that was a `v-b-tooltip` was a component and not a directive.

From what I can tell, using a variable in a directive isn't supported. One solution would be to use [`vue-popper`](https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-popper) since you can update its options dynamically. Bootstrap uses Popper under the hood for its tooltips, so you wouldn't be introducing new technologies this way.

Comment: v-b-tooltip is a directive, not a component. OP is trying to add a dynamic modifier to a directive.

Answer (score 1):

For **Bootstrap-Vue** tooltip there is parameter **placement**, so code could look like this:

```
<b-btn title="Title" target="d150" :placement="position">My btn</b-btn>
```

More at: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tooltip